# How to make \texttt in \itshaped sidepar look like \texttt in main text

Tags: italic, typewriter

I have side paragraphs in italics and I am using typewriter fonts in the main text to refer to code elements. I want to use the same font in my side paragraphs because it should be clear that it is the same concept and it gets messy with too many fonts. However I keep getting the italic monospace font. How can I get the non italic monospaced font? I have tried so many hacks but nothing seems to work...

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[lining]{ebgaramond}
\renewcommand*{\sideparfont}{\footnotesize\itshape}
\begin{document}
\sidepar{Lorem \texttt{foo-bar} ipsum}
Lorem ispum cit \texttt{foo-bar} dolor.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are two possible methods -- using `\textup` (which takes an argument, thus requiring another set of braces) or using `\upshape` (which can be included as the first element inside the `\texttt` group):

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[lining]{ebgaramond}
\renewcommand*{\sideparfont}{\footnotesize\itshape}
\begin{document}
\sidepar{Lorem \textup{\texttt{foo-bar}} ipsum}
Lorem ispum cit \texttt{foo-bar} dolor.

\sidepar{Lorem \texttt{\upshape foo-bar} ipsum}
Lorem ispum cit \texttt{foo-bar} dolor.
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

Answer (score 1):

You possibly want monospaced text to always appear upright; just redefine `\texttt` to do it: the usual definition is

```
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\texttt}{\ttfamily}
```

and we just need to add `\upshape`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[lining]{ebgaramond}

\renewcommand*{\sideparfont}{\footnotesize\itshape}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\texttt}{\ttfamily\upshape}

\begin{document}

\sidepar{Lorem \texttt{foo-bar} ipsum}
Lorem ispum cit \texttt{foo-bar} dolor.

\end{document}
```

[image]